# Combine for-loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 2 variables (brith and death time) like this:

```
df<-data_frame(birth=c(1945,1977,1919,1966),death=c(2011,2015,1980,2019))
```

I would like to count the alive numbers year 1995-2000, I wrote a for loop counter for it

## For year 1995

```
Man_counts <- 0
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  start<-df[row,"birth"]
  end<-df_m[row,"death"]
  if (start<=1995|end>=1995){
    Man_counts= Man_counts+1}}
```

## For Year 1996

```
Man_counts_2 <- 0
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  start<-df[row,"birth"]
  end<-df_m[row,"death"]
  if (start<=1996|end>=1996){
    Man_counts_2= Man_counts_2+1}}
```

And so on, for other years(1997-2000).
I failed to use a double loop to deal with it. Furthermore, a double loop sometimes run endless on my laptop.
I would like to know how to combine them in an elegant way so that I don't have to run 1995-2000 every year separately .

Th ideal output could be

```
output<-data_frame(year=1995:2000, alive_counts=c(2,2,2,2,3,3,))
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Man_counts <- 0
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  start<-df[row,"birth"]
  end<-df_m[row,"death"]
  if (start<=1995|end>=1995){
    Man_counts= Man_counts+1}}.  The "df_m" should be "df", sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` :

```
df<-data_frame(birth=c(1945,1977,1919,1966),death=c(2011,2015,1980,2019))
years <- 1995:2000

result <- data.frame(years, alive_counts = sapply(years, function(x) 
                                   sum(df$birth <= x & df$death >= x)))
```

Comment: Beat me by 43 seconds.